# Weka clustering methods greyed out

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, weka

I generated a csv file with 167 attributes and around 5000 entries. One is a nominal attribute, two are dates and the rest is numerical.

I can import the file into the weka explorer without problems. But all clustering methods and most attribute selectors are greyed out. This still happens if I delete around 50 of my attributes. I only found ideas how to make it work with classifier methods but I need clustering or at least attribute selection. I used similar data before but with only 20 attributes and it worked, so I guess I need to further reduce the amount of attributes? But I'd really like to make some algorithm chose instead of me.

Can you advise me what I could change? Are there other tools that work with this many attributes? Or did I do a obvious mistake I am not finding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many clustering algorithms only work with *continuous* values.

Therefore, they are greyed out until you convert all your attributes to numeric. But beware that the methods will still assume e.g. a similar scale. So mapping a date and a count to comparable values may simply be impossible.

Don't blindly use these algorithms as black box methods. This will produce useless / meaningless results. Instead, your job is to *understand* the algorithms and identify the way to transform the data (and often: how to *modify the algorithm*) that the result has **desirable properties for *your* problem**. You don't gain anything if the algorithm solves a different problem...

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I agree. But I don't think that this is the problem in my case. I understand the algorithms I want to work with (in this case I figured DBScan should be the most promising) and I know that - at least in theory - my features are fitting to be used with it. I still feel it is more guessing than knowing because I lack the experience but I have an idea of what to do. I am just dumbfounded because I wasn't able to use ANY algorithm at all and couldn't figure out why. Turns out, I screwed up in the export and had some badly formatted numbers. Thanks though :)

Comment: Weka DBSCAN is really slow. Use ELKI DBSCAN instead.

Answer (score 0):

For future references: Turns out I had a poorly formatted csv file because I made some changes in it through excel and it decided to place additional points in my numbers. Generated a new export and now it works.